Quantlib Python Yield Curve Construction Inconsistent

Why is it that my first method of looping through dates and creating curves on each date, fails on a specific day, but when creating a curve using only that dates data it does not?

I created a repo with the full code and data here
My df is a pandas dataframe of bond data, example on the date my issue appears:
>>> data
          date maturityDate  coupon Term      price     yield  yearsToMaturity
6   2024-07-23   01/12/2055  0.0275  30y   87.65970  3.392170        31.292349
7   2024-07-23   01/06/2034  0.0300  10y   96.76773  3.388122         9.836065
8   2024-07-23   01/06/2031  0.0150   7y   88.83253  3.334988         6.841530
9   2024-07-23   01/03/2029  0.0400   5y  102.82576  3.332821         4.595628
10  2024-07-23   01/09/2026  0.0100   3y   94.72333  3.621295         2.103825
11  2024-07-23   01/08/2026  0.0400   2y  100.57167  3.704362         2.019126

and depo_rates are a pandas dataframe of deposit rates, example:
>>> dataDepo
         date   rate  yearsToMaturity
3  2024-07-23  4.410          0.50000
4  2024-07-23  4.174          1.00000
5  2024-07-23  4.750          0.00274

This is the actual code
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('Data\\bond_data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True).dt.date
depo_rates = pd.read_csv('Data\\depo_data.csv')
depo_rates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(depo_rates['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.date
curveDates = df['date'].unique()
curveDict = dict.fromkeys(curveDates, None)

for date in curveDates:
    calc_date = ql.Date(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    data = df[(df['date'] == date)]
    dataDepo = depo_rates[depo_rates['date'] == date]
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

    maturities = data['yearsToMaturity'].tolist()
    maturities_depo = dataDepo['yearsToMaturity'].tolist()
    maturities_depo = [ql.Period(round(m*365), ql.Days) for m in maturities_depo]
    rates_depo = dataDepo['rate'].tolist()
    prices = data['price'].tolist()
    coupons = data['coupon'].tolist()
    maturities = [ql.Period(round(m*365), ql.Days) for m in maturities]
    calendar = ql.Canada()
    day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)
    business_convention = ql.Following
    end_of_month = False
    settlement_days = 1
    face_amount = 100
    coupon_frequency = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

    print("rates_deop: ", rates_depo)
    print("maturities_depo: ", maturities_depo)
    print("bond prices: ", prices)
    print("bond coupons: ", coupons)
    print("bond maturities: ", maturities)

    depo_helpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(r/100.0)),
    m,
    settlement_days,
    calendar,
    business_convention,
    end_of_month,
    day_count)
    for r, m in zip(rates_depo, maturities_depo)]

    bond_helpers = []

    for p, c , m in zip(prices, coupons, maturities):
        schedule = ql.Schedule(calc_date,
            calc_date + m,
            coupon_frequency,
            calendar,
            business_convention,
            business_convention,
            ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
            True)
        bond_helper = ql.FixedRateBondHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(p)),
        settlement_days,
        face_amount,
        schedule,
        [c],
        day_count,
        business_convention,
        )
        bond_helpers.append(bond_helper)
        
    rate_helpers = depo_helpers+bond_helpers 
    
    curveDict[date] = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(calc_date,
    rate_helpers,
    day_count)

yc = curveDict[dt.date(2024,7,23)]
start = 0
stop = 30
step = 0.25
sequence = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
points = []

compounding = ql.Continuous
freq = ql.Semiannual

for date in sequence:
   points.append(yc.zeroRate(date, compounding, freq).rate()*100)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sequence, points)), columns=["year", "rate"])

fig = px.line(df_1, x='year', y='rate')
fig.show()

This is the error from trying to extract the zero rates
RuntimeError: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar March 27th, 2025, maturity March 27th, 2025, reference date July 23rd, 2024: negative time (-0.0833333) given

This is the print statement for the data on that date,
    July 23rd, 2024
rates_deop:  [4.41, 4.174, 4.75]
maturities_depo:  [Period("182D"), Period("365D"), Period("1D")]
bond prices:  [87.6597, 96.76773, 88.83253, 102.82576, 94.72333, 100.57167]
bond coupons:  [0.0275, 0.03, 0.015, 0.04, 0.01, 0.04]
bond maturities:  [Period("11422D"), Period("3590D"), Period("2497D"), Period("1677D"), Period("768D"), Period("737D")]

However if I build a curve on the same date specifically it runs fine
the data being used appears the same,
rates_deop:  [4.41, 4.174, 4.75]
maturities_depo:  [Period("182D"), Period("365D"), Period("1D")]
bond prices:  [87.6597, 96.76773, 88.83253, 102.82576, 94.72333, 100.57167]
bond coupons:  [0.0275, 0.03, 0.015, 0.04, 0.01, 0.04]
bond maturities:  [Period("11422D"), Period("3590D"), Period("2497D"), Period("1677D"), Period("768D"), Period("737D")]


df = pd.read_csv('Data\\bond_data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True).dt.date
depo_rates = pd.read_csv('Data\\depo_data.csv')
depo_rates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(depo_rates['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.date
curveDates = df['date'].unique()
curveDict = dict.fromkeys(curveDates, None)

date = dt.date(2024,7,23)

calc_date = ql.Date(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
data = df[(df['date'] == date)]
dataDepo = depo_rates[depo_rates['date'] == date]
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

maturities = data['yearsToMaturity'].tolist()
maturities_depo = dataDepo['yearsToMaturity'].tolist()
maturities_depo = [ql.Period(round(m*365), ql.Days) for m in maturities_depo]
rates_depo = dataDepo['rate'].tolist()
prices = data['price'].tolist()
coupons = data['coupon'].tolist()
maturities = [ql.Period(round(m*365), ql.Days) for m in maturities]
calendar = ql.Canada()
day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)
business_convention = ql.Following
end_of_month = False
settlement_days = 1
face_amount = 100
coupon_frequency = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

print("rates_deop: ", rates_depo)
print("maturities_depo: ", maturities_depo)
print("bond prices: ", prices)
print("bond coupons: ", coupons)
print("bond maturities: ", maturities)

depo_helpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(r/100.0)),
m,
settlement_days,
calendar,
business_convention,
end_of_month,
day_count)
for r, m in zip(rates_depo, maturities_depo)]

bond_helpers = []

for p, c , m in zip(prices, coupons, maturities):
    schedule = ql.Schedule(calc_date,
        calc_date + m,
        coupon_frequency,
        calendar,
        business_convention,
        business_convention,
        ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
        True)
    bond_helper = ql.FixedRateBondHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(p)),
    settlement_days,
    face_amount,
    schedule,
    [c],
    day_count,
    business_convention,
    )
    bond_helpers.append(bond_helper)
    
rate_helpers = depo_helpers+bond_helpers 

crv = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(calc_date,
    rate_helpers,
    day_count)

yc = crv
start = 0
stop = 30
step = 0.25
sequence = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
points = []

compounding = ql.Continuous
freq = ql.Semiannual

for date in sequence:
   points.append(yc.zeroRate(date, compounding, freq).rate()*100)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sequence, points)), columns=["year", "rate"])

fig2 = px.line(df_2, x='year', y='rate')
fig2.show()



For the example tables you have provided: depo_rates = depo_rates[(depo_rates['date'] >= dt.date(2024,7,1))] and depo_rates = depo_rates[(depo_rates['date'] >= dt.date(2024,7,1)) & (depo_rates['date'] <= dt.date(2024,7,15))] are the same thing. In your real data they may be different. Is the crux of your question "when using different data why do I get a different output?" That would typically be expected and if you want to explore it, it will require delving into the devil of the details of the data (assuming there is also no other issue with the code)

@Attack68 I've added a repo with the full code and also a better example that should show the issue better. Obviously I would expect different data to produce different curves but it appears I'm using the data for curve creation.
